# NSCollectionView inside NSTabViewController

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscollectionview, macos-high-sierra

I am facing a strange behavior of NSCollectionView inside a NSTabViewController.

I think that this issue appeared when I upgraded to High Sierra (not sure though).

My app has four tabs and each of them contains a collection view:

[image]

When I launch the app, the first tab is fine, problem is when I switch to other tabs. The collection view is not properly laid out:

[image]

As soon as I touch the window border the collection view reorganizes normally.

I tried to force the collection view to layout (.collectionView.layout()) without success.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue. I tried to force update the layout, constraints, and display, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: See my own answer below

Answer (score 1):

This helped me out:

1. Subclassed the NSTabViewController
2. Added this:

   ```
   override func tabView(_ tabView: NSTabView, didSelect tabViewItem: NSTabViewItem?) {

      let controller = tabViewItem?.viewController as? MyController
      controller?.collectionView.frame = (controller?.view.frame)!
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem recently and the provided fix didn't work with my particular subview layout, but this did:

```
override func tabView(_ tabView: NSTabView, didSelect tabViewItem: NSTabViewItem?) {
  if let controller = tabViewItem?.viewController as? MyController,
     let collectionView = controller.collectionView,
     let contentSize = collectionView.collectionViewLayout?.collectionViewContentSize,
     contentSize.height > collectionView.frame.size.height
  {
     collectionView.frame.size.height = contentSize.height
  }
}
```

Maybe this is a more generally applicable solution.